# JavaScript Arrow functions understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arrow-functions

I have this function:

```
$(".tabstrip li").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id") == "searchlist" ? $(this).addClass("selected") : $(this).removeClass("selected");
    })
```

Now i was asking myself, if I can make this shorter. So I tried this:

```
$(".tabstrip li").each(() => $(this).attr("id") == "searchlist" ? $(this).addClass("selected") : $(this).removeClass("selected"))
```

And it don't worked. How I understood arrow functions this should be correct.

(There is no error too)

Do someone understand this? Its not important but I cant sleep until i figure out why this don't work ;)

Thank you for your time ^^

Comment: `this` isn't what you thought it was, you have to pass the variables to the arrow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions set the value of `this` inside them so it is the same as the value of `this` outside them.

This breaks your code, because a regular function called by `each` will have a value of `this` based on the current value being looped over (and your function depends on that being the case).

---

Do not use arrow functions "to make code shorter". That isn't what they are for. Arrow functions are for controlling the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it short like this. I don't think using `ES6 Arrow Functions` is the best for browser support.

```
$(".tabstrip li").each(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected", this.id == "searchlist");
})
```

Comment: I have to toggle off "selected" from the other <li> that is selected when I'm on "index". But thank you for your answer :D